# Change description paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I using Recurring Payment Express Checkout.

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_ec?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

I want change description same image:

[image]

Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You must use parameters

> DESC and L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0

Paypal Documentation:

> Add an L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTIONn field to correspond to each L_BILLINGTYPEn field you pass; **n** is a value in the range of 0 to 9, inclusive. Set the value of each field to the description of the goods or services associated with that billing agreement
>
> DESC: The same description as you used in SetExpressCheckout.